# "The php script was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type" error

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to insert data to oracle database using php from a bootstrap form. Whenever I try to execute the html file in mozilla firefox following error occurs:

> The script from
> “http://localhost/CustomerPartInAsma/CUSTOMER%20part%20in%20ASMA/Customer_register.php”
> was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid
> JavaScript MIME type

My html code and php code is given below:

HTML code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Business Casual - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/business-casual.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/employee.css" rel="stylesheet">
 

</head>

<body>

  
  <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-lg-4" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase text-expanded font-weight-bold d-lg-none" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
           <li class="nav-item px-lg-4">
            <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="index2.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-lg-4">
            <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="about2.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-lg-4">
            <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="services2.html">Services</a>
          </li>
           <li class="nav-item px-lg-4">
            <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="gallery2.html">Gallery</a>
          </li>
           
           <li class="nav-item active px-lg-4">
            <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="logout.html">Login
            </a>
          
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


    <body>

      
  

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-9 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-signin flex-row my-5">
          <div class="card-img-left d-none d-md-flex">
             <!-- Background image for card set in CSS! -->
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center">Register</h3>
            <form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action="Customer_register.php">
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="inputUsername"class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputUserame">Full Name</label>
              </div>

              
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputContactNo" name="inputContactNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact No" required>
                <label for="inputContactNo">Contact No</label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputAddress"  name="inputAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required>
                <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputAllergies"  name="inputAllergies" class="form-control" placeholder="Allergies" required>
                <label for="inputAllergies">Allergies</label>
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputSkinType" name="inputSkinType" class="form-control" placeholder="Skin Type" required>
                <label for="inputSkinType">Skin Type</label>
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputHairType"  name="inputHairType" class="form-control" placeholder="Hair Type" required>
                <label for="inputHairType">Hair Type</label>
              </div>
              
              
              <hr>

              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="password" id="inputConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <label for="inputConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
              </div>

              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit" formaction="index.html" name= "submit">Register</button>
              <a class="d-block text-center mt-2 small" href="login.html">Sign In</a>
              <hr class="my-4">
              
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>






 
  <footer class="footer text-faded text-center py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 small">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
 
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP code

```
<?php


    $conn=oci_connect("ASMADB","asmadb","localhost/XE");
    if(!$conn)
        echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
    else
        echo 'successful';
    

    $name = $_POST['inputUsername'];
    $phn = $_POST['inputContactno'];
  $add = $_POST['inputAddress'];
  $s_type= $_POST['inputSkinType'];
    $h_type = $_POST['inputHairType'];
      $allergies = $_POST['inputAllergies'];
      $C_pass=  $_POST['inputPassword'];
        
         


    

    $sql="INSERT into customer values('','$name','',0.0,'$s_type','$h_type','$allergies','$phn','$add',1,'$rating','$C_pass')";


    
    $objParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

    $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);

    if($objExecute)

    {

        oci_commit($conn); 

        echo "Save completed.";
        

    }

    else

    {
        oci_rollback($conn); 

        $m = oci_error($objParse);

        echo "Error Save [".$m['message']."]";

    }
     
    oci_close($conn);

    ?>
```

It will be very helpful if someone helps me to resolve this error and insert data to my oracle db.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Also, your PHP script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I'm not being able to insert data for this error. Can you please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: "Also, your PHP script is vulnerable to SQL injection." Will you please explain? and suggest some modification if needed?? @Dai

Comment: You shouldn't plug in information into the sql query directly. Google how an sql injection occurs. Someone could put in malicious string into the name field and access your DB

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="Customer_register.php"></script>`

It looks like you are trying to load a PHP file as JavaScript code. Is this a mistake?

If not, your browser is rejecting the dynamic JavaScript you are trying to load. You have to give the MIME type of JavaScript to the browser. Add this to the top of your Customer_register.php file:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: the php file is only added in this part :   `<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action="Customer_register.php">`  (The code is edited)  even after adding the part : `header("Content-type: text/javascript");` the php file is not loading!

Comment: I'm just confused why you are POSTing data to a file that you have linked as JavaScript.